# calculate merkle root from 2 transaction

Tags: c++, root, sha256

I want to prove the calculation of Merkle root for bitcoin, but I can't get the same root as shown on block explorer.

Data from block explorer (https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/block/80000)

```
tx1 hash = "c06fbab289f723c6261d3030ddb6be121f7d2508d77862bb1e484f5cd7f92b25"
tx2 hash = "5a4ebf66822b0b2d56bd9dc64ece0bc38ee7844a23ff1d7320a88c5fdb2ad3e2"
Merkle Root = "8fb300e3fdb6f30a4c67233b997f99fdd518b968b9a3fd65857bfe78b2600719"
```

Now what I do is, first I reverse the order of TX1 and TX2 to become

```
tx1 hash reverse = "252BF9D75C4F481EBB6278D708257D1F12BEB6DD30301D26C623F789B2BA6FC0"
tx2 hash reverse = "E2D32ADB5F8CA820731DFF234A84E78EC30BCE4EC69DBD562D0B2B8266BF4E5A"
```

Then I combine both string and hash it using sha256 from web (https://xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator)

```
so first hash i got answer = "9a5c2897b8d01cb7996867e01b70bb1a4c84190982bd71d55d1efe5320feee22"

second hash = Merkle root = "437b30772522751ee150eb4b0a9c246d28557036cd720f75aecbba32ea59d174"

but answer from block hash is = "8fb300e3fdb6f30a4c67233b997f99fdd518b968b9a3fd65857bfe78b2600719"
```

I tried also to do it in C++ using the hashlib++ library and the answer is same as above but not equal to the root shown in block explorer.

So where is my understanding wrong? I need help to pin point my correction.

Comment: You should include the relevant code in the question. See this to get the idea: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

I tried your example and got the exact correct answer, not sure if you are doing this right, please see my code below written in Python to make it easier for you to calculate:

```
X1a = binascii.unhexlify("c06fbab289f723c6261d3030ddb6be121f7d2508d77862bb1e484f5cd7f92b25")[::-1]
X1b = binascii.unhexlify("5a4ebf66822b0b2d56bd9dc64ece0bc38ee7844a23ff1d7320a88c5fdb2ad3e2")[::-1]
Y = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(X1a + X1b).digest()).digest()[::-1]
Z = binascii.hexlify(Y)
print Z
```

To explain my code:

1. Lines (1 and 2) takes your string and converts it into a byte array, it then reverses it with the [::-1] at the end of that line, so, your 11223344 would become 44,33,22,11
2. Line 3 does a Double-SHA256 of the concatenated byte arrays and then also reverse the byte order
3. Line 4 converts the byte array into a hex string, this is for printing or sending somewhere.
4. Line 5 is the printing/output.

This works and returns the output of "8fb300e3fdb6f30a4c67233b997f99fdd518b968b9a3fd65857bfe78b2600719" which is the correct answer as submitted by you initially, also matches the block you referenced.